# Airflow supported cross data center?

Tags: airflow, data-pipeline

We would like to use Apache Airflow to orchestrate work across global data centers (regions).  From what I can tell the only way to make this work is to give access/permission to all tasks to write directly to some cloud exposed database.  Does anyone know of a better way to implement this?  I would prefer there was a way for tasks to communicate back to the central Airflow database asynchronously through a message queue, but I've seen no mention of that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, a central database for Airflow internals is required. You can't escape from it right now.

See the doc: https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html?highlight=initdb#setting-up-a-backend